# How to apply css for anchor tag inside table

Tags: html, css

i am trying to apply the css for the anchor tag which is inside the table. but i am not able to see any changes. 
 how to do this?

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table.tab>td>a
{
background-color:yellow;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table class="tab">
<tr><td><a href="#">google.com</a></td></tr>
</tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And `>` is the child combinator – but `td` is not a child of `table`. (And even if you put an additional `tr` in there, it might still not work, because of the `tbody` element in between that browsers will create implicitly.)

Comment: Why don't you just make a class for the `<a>`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
table.tab td a{
background-color:yellow;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Close your table correctly and use selector without >. So:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table.tab td a
{
background-color:yellow;

}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table class="tab">
<tr><td><a href="#">google.com</a></td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
table.tab td a
{
   background-color:yellow;
}
```

`>` *Selects all direct child elements specified by "child" of elements specified by "parent".*

ChildSelector [*API*](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost correct. this works for me:

```
<style type="text/css">
    table.tab td a
    {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
</style>
<table class="tab">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="#">google.com</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it like the following:

```
table.tab td a {

    background-color: yellow;

}
```

a '>' selects all direct child elements specified by a `child` that are specified by the `parent`

Answer (score 0):

```
table a
{
background-color:yellow;
}
```

This should solve your issue.